# Proving that $A^{T}A = M$ for all symmetric complex matrices $M$.

Tags: matrices, algebraic-geometry

I am trying to prove that the map $M_{n}(\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow $ nxn Symmetric matrices $\cong \mathbb{C}^{n(n+1)/2}$, given by $A \rightarrow A^{T}A$ is surjective. I have shown that this map maps into an open dense set (in the Zariski topology) of $\mathbb{C}^{n(n+1)/2}$.. I have been trying to conclude from this that the map is indeed surjective. Are there any tips on how I may show that this is a closed map?

Thanks!

Elliot

Comment: Note that for real matrices, the map is not surjective, because $A^T A$ would be positive definite.  How does working with symmetric complex matrices affect this?

Comment: Well, in $\mathbb{C}$ one may use the zariski topology to use some dense to global results..

Comment: @Elliot this map is indeed surjective!  You should look up proofs of the "Takagi factorization"

Comment: @hardmath it makes all the difference.  $A^*A$ is Hermitian positive definite.  $A^TA$ is symmetric, and that's all we can say.

Comment: @Elliot you should be able to find all of this in Horn and Johnson, for example.

Comment: @Elliot look also for "algebraic polar decomposition"

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks for the references! Do you have a source for "algebraic polar decomposition"? Thanks. Also, do you have any sources for the particular proof of the Takagi factorization theorem you are referring to? Thanks!

Comment: You don't need Tagaki factorisation. That the said map is surjective follows from a more elementary fact: every symmetric bilinear form over a field of characteristic $\ne2$ is diagonalisable. Now, if $M=P^TDP$ is such a diagonalisation, you may take $A=\sqrt{D}P$, where $\sqrt{D}$ is any entrywise complex square root of $D$.

Comment: @user1551 Could you please make this into an answer?

Comment: @user1551 I've never heard of such a fact. Any references for diagonalizing bilinear forms over fields besides $\Bbb R$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $A\mapsto A^T A$ is given by homogeneous polynomials. It induces a morphism $\mathbb P^{n^2} \to \mathbb P^{n(n+1)/2}$. Since any projective morphism is closed, so is this one. Consequently, the original map on the affine cones is also closed.

Comment: Of course! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

*(This answer does not show that the mapping in question is closed. Rather, it directly proves that the mapping is surjective.)*

Every symmetric bilinear form over a field of characteristic $\ne2$ is diagonalisable (see, e.g. [prop. 4.5](https://books.google.com/books?id=yjkgNYfApj4C&pg=PA179&lpg=PA179&dq=symmetric%20bilinear%20form%20over%20a%20field%20of%20characteristic%20%E2%89%A02%E2%89%A02%20is%20diagonalisable&source=bl&ots=qb3yDOwOGO&sig=5_2emcqgVdc91ykqnmzX6_PDIaw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJxKi-0rPKAhXCjJQKHST3BwwQ6AEIKTAC#v=onepage&q=symmetric%20bilinear%20form%20over%20a%20field%20of%20characteristic%20%E2%89%A02%E2%89%A02%20is%20diagonalisable&f=false) of *Linear Algebra* written by Sahai and Bist (2003)). That is, if $M$ is symmetric, then $M=P^TDP$ for some invertible matrix $P$ and some diagonal matrix $D$. If the field is also quadratically closed, then $M=A^TA$ when $A=\sqrt{D}P$ and $\sqrt{D}$ is any entrywise square root of $D$. Hence the mapping in question is surjective.

Comment: Great, thanks! I accepted Jesko's answer because having an AG proof of this result was more important to me.